# Para que serve o $scope.$apply ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Eu vi em um código o $scope.$apply que utiliza AngularJS, para que ele serve ? No contexto em que se encontra está desta forma:

```
var a = function(param){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                var image = document.getElementById('img');
                image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + param;
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 13):

No Angular 1.x, versão corrente, alterações feitas "por fora" do angular não são identificadas por ele, `$scope.apply()` ou `$scope.digest()` fazem o trabalho de solicitar ao angular que revise suas variáveis em busca de modificações externas. Note que ai neste exemplo de código, a função dentro do apply busca na estrutura da página com o `document.getElementById` (que é um meio por fora do angular), um elemento que possivelmente é gerenciado pelo angular e o altera.

É importante alertar, que `$scope.apply()` diz ao angular, "Hey, alterei algo! Se vire para descobrir o que foi." então ele irá buscar em toda a raiz de elementos gerenciados pelas possíveis alterações, o que pode ser bem ruim em questão de performance. O `$scope.digest()` faz a mesma coisa, mas apenas do scopo atual para baixo.

Mais informações aqui na documentação: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Apenas para complementar, eu citei Angular 1.x pois no Angular 2, segundo a documentação essas modificações fora do scope, serão detectadas automaticamente.